# Uniform convergence of a sequence of integrals

Tags: complex-analysis, uniform-convergence

Suppose that $f_n(t;z)\to f(t;z)$ with $z$ a complex parameter, such that
$$g(z) = \int_Af(t;z)dt,$$
and
$$g(z)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_Af_n(t;z)dt,$$
hold, where $A$ is some real interval, e.g. $(1,3)$, $(1,\infty)$, etc.

Do these conditions imply $\int_A f_n\to g$ uniformly ? Or maybe this is not true.

Comment: Not without further assumptions. $f_n(t;z) = \frac{1}{n}g(t)z \to 0$, but if $\int_A g(t)\,dt \neq 0$, then $\int_A f_n(t;z)\,dt$ doesn't converge to $0$ uniformly.